# Bypassing being FORCED to login with PIN...(which I do not have)

Tags: windows, microsoft

I finally broke-down and bought the lame Windows 10 upgrade (just in time for them to hock Windows 11 now...as if they have "mastered" Windows 10.  Man, what a bunch of freaking crooks.)

Anyway, I had previously set-up the particular laptop in question (not the machine I am on now, because I CANNOT ACCESS the other) with FINGERPRINT RECOGNITION and for a week or so, I was able to use my UNIQUE FINGERPRINT to log into that machine.

NOW all of a sudden, it will ONLY ALLOW ME TO LOGIN using a PIN #...which of course I never set-up and/or do not know where the #$&@% I can find the PIN for that machine.

So, I am completely stuck, unable to log-in, down $150 bucks as well from their (____) product, which I cannot use.

What should I do next, since MS's support is so "fantastic" that you cannot speak to anyone live (as they say, to help you get your answers faster...which we all know is BULLSHIT...they just don't want to spend money on personnel for tech support so that Bill Gates' weasely ass can keep even more billions.)

Secondary question, but really my potential primary one: can you set up a machine using Linux as the OS so that you don't need to rely on MS, GOOG and/or Apple anymore?  Someone honest figure that out, and sell "clean machines" to those of us that don't trust MS and the like anymore...

HELP!....help?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Simply put: yes, you can use Linux as an OS on most machines. However, aside from counterproductive verbiage, you have provide *no* information, so are unlikely to get a helpful answer in how to accomplish that.

Comment: You may want to remove your rant from the post - if you do you might attract answers that can help.

Comment: The PIN did not come from nowhere. For a fingerprint reader to work for logging in to Windows 10 you must have run through the “Windows Hello” setup procedure which will have given you the choice for setting up the PIN as a backup.

Comment: Gosh, everyone...thank you for sticking up for Microsoft, as they need all the support they can get, unlike their customers obviously.  Hey #2 -- I tried to delete this (#1) "counterproductive" rant but now that "others have invested time and effort," I can't even do that.  Thank you #3 for at least taking me one step closer, but whether or not I set-up an original PIN, I do not know what it is now, so yay.  [part 1]

Comment: I was asking, since I have (#1) "provided no information" in my original rant: 1. if fingerprint recognition is set-up and is the most uniquely secure method available, why would I be forced to use another method which at best I used years ago, and unlike all of you IT gurus I wasn't thinking I'd need to use the PIN as a log-in, and, question 2. how do you get around this, to "force" precious Microsoft to allow my fingerprint to be used just one more time to get a new PIN set-up, and maybe even start using a password.  Pippik & davidgo: no need for you two to invest anymore time/effort.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot readily separate the problems from the rant.

**Your login:**  You would have set up an account - likely a Microsoft Account and less likely local, especially because the machine has a fingerprint reader.

Whichever you set up, there would be a user name and password. You cannot set up Fingerprint reader without user name and password. You can leave PIN out but should not.

Now when you get the login screen requesting PIN, see the line of option icons below that. Click on the password icon and log in with username and password.

I often use the options icon for user name and password. That bypasses PIN. Works fine.

Then if you have a Microsoft Account, you can login to Microsoft Live and see your account. You can use your password to access that.

**Can you wipe out the machine and install Linux?** Yes, you can do that. You should be sure to use Ubuntu or Fedora which are compatible with UEFI and Secure Boot which I am sure you have. I recommend Ubuntu as a good stable choice.

Before you do that, check Windows Setup Recovery options and you should be able to make a recovery USB Key in case you or someone else wishes to return to Windows.

I believe I have answered you questions. Ranting does not help. I have Windows 10 here, Fingerprint reader, PIN, Microsoft Account, Ubuntu 20.04 and Kali 2021.3 where I am working now.

Good luck with setting up.